# $L(1,\chi_d)$ for even d

Tags: nt.number-theory

This question concerns the asymptotic maximum of $L(1,\chi_d)/ \log \log d$ when
$d$ is even.  I computed it  for even $d$ less than 7.5 million.  The largest
value is  $1.230126$,  occurring for $d= 2552806$. This value is never exceeded for the next five million $d$.   Languasco (arXiv:2005.04664v2 [math.NT] 26 May 2020) made
similar numerical computations without assuming $d$ is even and got a much
larger maximum of 2.21.   Can anyone explain why $L(1,\chi_d)$ should be smaller
for even $d$?   In particular,  for infinitely many $d$ we know (on GRH maybe) that
the value $e^{\gamma} = 1.781\ldots $ is exceeded,  but apparently not by even $d$.

Comment: Also,  if someone can kindly point me to instructions for including an image with a question,  I would post a cute graph here.

Comment: One heuristic model for the distribution of $L(1,\chi_d)$ is a product of Euler factors $(1 - \chi(p)/p)^{-1}$ where each $\chi(p)$ is chosen independently from $\{-1,0,+1\}$ with appropriate probabilities.  The $p=2$ factor has the largest effect, and can be $2$, $1$, or $2/3$.  Requiring $2|d$ makes that factor $1$, which we can expect to roughly halve the maximal $L(1,\chi_d)$.

Comment: For images, see the last paragraphs at https://mathoverflow.net/help/formatting